# Question about eigenvalues

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this :
[image]

i dont understand why  they write $\lambda=m^2 , m\in \mathbb{N}\cup\lbrace0\rbrace$ ,

it's right that $\lambda=m^2$ is the eigenvalues of $(P_0)$ ,but $0$ is not an eigenvalue !.

after that why they  write $\mathbb{N}\cup \lbrace0\rbrace$ 0 already belongs to $\mathbb{N}$ !

Please, help me

Thank you.

Comment: Note that not all people define $\mathbb{N}$ to be the nonnegative integers $\{0,1,2,3,...\}$. Some people define $\mathbb{N}$ to be the positive integers $\{1,2,3,...\}$. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_numbers

Comment: but 0 is not an eigenvalue !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero is an eigenvalue. Let $x(t)=1$ to see this.

Whether or not zero is a natural number depends on your definition of $\mathbb N$ which is not standardized. Either convention can be used.

Comment: whene $\lambda=0$ the unique solution is x=0 so 0 is not an eigenvalue ,or no ?

Comment: x(t)=0 is a solution for (P_0) we have $0=x''=\lambda * 1 $ son $\lambda=0$ , then 0 is an eigenvalue ??

Comment: Dude, I told you $x(t)=1$! You can't have $x(t)=0$.

Comment: yes yes it is a striking erreure ,x(t)=1 then 0=x''=\lambda *1 so $\lambda=0$ !

Comment: OK, so you're happy that zero is an eigenvalue? I'm not sure whether you're happy that I answered the question yet (:

Comment: i'm happy to understand , and thank you for your answer , please do you know what is a resonance or double resonance ? thank you